# After adding rasters to mosaic I can't see new raster without zooming in

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, mosaic

Trying to merge rasters to mosaic with properties shown in picture below. After finishing, I can see new raster only after zooming in. Anybody knows how can I see raster without zooming in?

I tried with 'Maximum Pyramid Levels Used' being 0 and 20 but nothing's changing.

[image: properties for adding rasters to mosaic]

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in parallel processing - it has to be set up with 0